# Black to move and mate in 3

Tags: problems

I found this interesting problem on Reddit. If this position appears in Britz's game of mine, I also would miss this.

```
[FEN "5r1r/ppk3p1/8/2bB4/3n4/7b/PP4PP/RN1QR1K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Please anyone can tell me, why FEN automatically convert to the chessboard in this question (this is my first question on chess.stackexchange),

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment - but if you are asking how to make a FEN display as a chess border simply select it in the editor and click on {} - it will take a second two two but if your browser is capable it will then display the board

Answer (score 2):

> 1. ..Ne2+
>  2. Kh1 Ng3+
>  3. hxNg3 Bg4# with the rook h8

Very nice puzzle !

Answer (score 1):

There is a very obvious start with the double check Ne2. After that you just need to spot that the h8 rook is lined up on the king's only square, h1. The only problem is how to clear the white pawn and black bishop off the file to give checkmate:

```
[fen "5r1r/ppk3p1/8/2bB4/3n4/7b/PP4PP/RN1QR1K1 b - - 0 1"]

1. Ne2+ Kh1 2. Ng3+ hxg3 3. Bg4++
```